# Changing the distance between vanishing points

Tags: camera

I'm trying to teach myself [two-point perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_(graphical)#Two-point_perspective) in drawing, and to do so, I want to create different cube-like objects in a 3D modeling program, and see how they related to the vanishing points. I downloaded and installed Blender, essentially yesterday, just for this project.

However, when I try to render a cube, the vanishing points are spaced so far apart, opposite edges are nearly parallel. Is there a way to somehow adjust the vanishing points, to make the parallel-line convergence effect stronger?

This is what I've got going for myself so far:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the Focal Length to a smaller value to adjust the perspective.

The Focal Length can be set separately for any Camera as well as for the Viewport. To adjust the Viewport, simply open the Properties panel of the 3D Viewport (press <kbd>N</kbd>) and scroll down to View as shown and change the 'Lens' setting.

For the Camera, select the Camera and open the Camera properties panel and change the Focal Length as desired.

[image]